# Is there a way to use Material-UI Chip component to display two bits of data with a column-type of layout?

Tags: material-ui

Right now, I'm passing two bits of data to the "label" attribute. So the "name" and "email" are rendering side-by-side.

```
             <Chip
              label={`${option.name} ${option.email}`}
              style={{
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                backgroundColor: '#00E5B9', 
                borderRadius: '1px', 
                marginLeft: '10px',
                marginTop: '10px'
              }}
              onDelete={() => handleDelete(option.tag)}
            />
```

I'm looking for a way to get them to render in a column-type of fashion with the name above the email.

So far I've tried the following without success:

- Adding a newline character \n in the label `label={`${option.name} \n ${option.email}`}`
- Putting the email as part of the content `<Chip label={option.name}> {option.email}</Chip>`

I've read through the documentation but so far I haven't found a way to do it.

Can anyone recommend an approach that would work?

Answer (score 0):

I've got stuck for the same things at work and the only way to do it was to create the whole chip by hand with css/html unfortunately...

You should open an issue on the git repository of MUI and ask them to add this feature to the chip component.

```html
<div className={classes.chip}>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
</div>
```

and add styling on your own too:

```css
  chip: {
    color: "crimson",
    border: "1px solid crimson",
    borderRadius: theme.spacing(3.125),
  },
```

Comment: Thank you! I was pretty sure I might have to go down that road but now I'm certain.

Comment: Unfortunately yes is the only way to do this.. Sometime MUI is not really useful and you can reach the maximum of what the library can do really fast .. Mark my answer as useful and accept it if it's answer your question  Have a good day !